# Aws auto scaling group failure for elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, autoscaling

So my elasticbeanstalk has been successfully deployed. However autoscaling seems to be an issue

ASG configo

`Desired = 2`

`Min = 2`

`Max 4`

I have enough instance for the instance type i am using.

When i test my app, just to simulate load, the instances increases to 3, but fails when it tries to bring up another(4th) instance with below errors

**Description**: Launching a new EC2 instance.

**Status Reason**: Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1. Launching EC2 instance failed.

**Reason**: an instance was started in response to a difference between desired and actual capacity, increasing the capacity from

Im i missing something somewhere ? 
Links will be quite helpfull is some one has seen this before

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the error :

`Status Reason: Your quota allows for 0 more running instance(s). You requested at least 1.`

From the error message it shows you have **hit the limit of EC2 instances**. Please check how many instances you are running.

The specifics on the limits can be found in the FAQ [here](https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/faqs/#How_many_instances_can_I_run_in_Amazon_EC2)

You can request limit increase as explained [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-resource-limits.html)

Thanks

Comment: limit of EC2 instances is fine, that was my first thought. Checked and sure everything is fine with limit.

Comment: With this error message, you are indeed hitting the limit. How many running EC2 instances do you have and what is your limit?

Comment: Everyone was right, with EC2 limit. The point is aws tells you have have 50 x type of instance, but caps the amount of running instance. A bit confusing but got this resolving by simply requesting to increase the instance.